# Pitch of FPC connector

Tags: fpc

I need to interface a display which has an FPC connector. I'm a bit confused as to what is the pin pitch. The datasheet's drawing is a bit confusing because the dimension lines are a bit off-centered with regards to the pin's midpoint. If someone could help me out, that'd be great.

[image: Mechanical drawing]

[Datasheet of display](http://www.dirsys.ru/upload/iblock/164/164cb7d218bfdbaca0bc2d7013f1aaae.pdf)

Comment: It would appear that is saying it is 0.3 mm - which is a standard size.  Perhaps put a metric ruler next to it and examine under a microscope...  Or model the whole thing in a PCB cad program, print it out at 1:1 and compare to that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't have the display with me now. Can you guess what "0.5*p(33-1)=16" means. Is it referring to pin pitch?

Comment: @ChrisStratton No, 0.3 is the width (W) of the pin copper area. The pitch  is 0.5mm, as implied by the formula they give. Besides, although a 0.3mm pitch is standard, such connectors typically use a staggered pin layout.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for the hint, even I suspected the same thing.

Comment: Good point on using the pinncount multiplied width.  Anyway that's why I recommended a visual comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I coloured the pins the make the picture a bit more clear.

[image]

0.5p*(33-1)=16 is indeed referring to the pitch.
The measure is taken from the middle of the 1<sup>st</sup> pin to the the middle of the 33<sup>rd</sup> pin *(first hint)*.
The centre line is nicely<sup>(1)</sup> draw in the middle of the middle pin, pin 17 *(second hint)*.
The drawing is written in mm, so:
0.5p * (33 pin positions - 1) = 16 mm

Since the pin positions are dimensionless, 0.5p must have the dimension mm *(third hint)*.
So, based on the centre lines and units, I am quite positive they mean:

**0.5 mm_pitch**  * (33 pin positions - 1) = 16 mm

The pin's width is 0.30 mm (I think that's where the 'w' stands for, *(fourth hint)* and the pin's height is 3.00 mm (plus shown tolerances).

This pin's width of 0.30 mm with the pin's pitch of 0.50 mm also makes sense *(fifth hint)*: it leaves a 0.20 mm clearance between the pins.

The left measure "0.50 mm ± 0.10 mm" is the distance of the centre of pin 1 with respect to the left edge of the PCB, so, it is not referring to the pitch size *(sixth hint)*.

Based on these 6 hints, I am quite positive **the pitch is 0.5 mm**

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I agree: not perfectly, but I think clear enough.

Comment: Even I had the same exact thoughts. Just needed confirmation, thanx dude.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort of using colors.